# How to change font size in message box in eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I want to display the message with larger font than the usual size in the message box. I don't know how to do this task. I also searched trying google but couldn't find a solution. Is there any way in eclipse rcp to accomplish this task ?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what kind of "message box" do you open. Generally there is:

1. SWT message box API (`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox`) - this uses the OS system message box and can be customized only with title, text and icon type (error, info, question,...).
2. JFace message dialog API (`org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog`) - this uses "Basic->Dialog" font defined in "Colors and Fonts" preference page. See the code in `org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog#createTitleArea` method which attaches a listener to the JFaceResources.getFontRegistry()

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Windows->Preferences pane
    General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts